# Quickest way to create symmetric vincenty-distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, foreach, parallel-processing, geospatial

I have a list of coordinates (cc) which I would like to turn into a distance matrix using the "distVincentyEllipsoid" function in R.

The slow way is:

```
distmat <- apply(cc, 1, FUN=function(X) distVincentyEllipsoid(X, cc))
```

However, for around 5000 coordinates this takes 4,227 seconds. Since my final matrix will be symmetric I just want to calculate the lower triangle; so my idea was to: 1) create the pairwise combinations in a nested foreach loop and then 2) reshape this into the matrix I need:

```
 X <- diag(p) 
    X[upper.tri(X, diag=TRUE)] <- elements 
    X <- X + t(X) - diag(diag(X)
```

I can't quite get the first part to work, for example: below I have experimented with just create the ordering I would like:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Create SAMPLE data-frame from 1 to 100 
sample_df <- data.frame(seq(1:100))
names(sample_df) <- c("id")

# Output should have 100*99/2 rows = 4950
output <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=nrow(sample_df)*(nrow(sample_df)-1)/2)

do_par_combos <- foreach(a=1:(nrow(sample_df))) %:%
                    foreach(b=(a+1):(nrow(sample_df)-1)) %dopar% {
                      # At the moment just create two columns with the IDs
                      # Expecting: [1,2],[1,3],..,[1,100],[2,3],.
                      output[counter,1] <- sample_df[a,c("id")]
                      output[counter,2] <- sample_df[b,c("id")]
                      counter = counter + 1
                    }


# RUN
do_par_combos
# Close processes
stopCluster(cl = cl)
```

My output is just full of NAs. I think this is because I can't run a counter in parallel as it will get over-written? I am curious about:

1. Making this parallel for-each loop work (even if it's not the quickest way to create the symmetric vincenty distance matrix)
2. Learning about the quickest way to create the symmetric vincenty distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `distm` function in the `geosphere` package to create a distance matrix:

```
library(geosphere)
cc <- rbind(c(0,0),
            c(90,90),
            c(10,10),
            c(-120,-45),
            c(45, 45))

dist_mat <- distm(cc, fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)
dist_mat
##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
## [1,]        0 10001966  1565109 12317881  6662473
## [2,] 10001966        0  8896111 14986910  5017021
## [3,]  1565109  8896111        0 13879039  5122094
## [4,] 12317881 14986910 13879039        0 18839623
## [5,]  6662473  5017021  5122094 18839623        0

as.dist(dist_mat, diag = TRUE)
##          1        2        3        4        5
## 1        0                                    
## 2 10001966        0                           
## 3  1565109  8896111        0                  
## 4 12317881 14986910 13879039        0         
## 5  6662473  5017021  5122094 18839623        0
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to run that in parallel however? Otherwise unless I'm missing something it doesn't seem faster? It also seems to calculate both sides of the triangular matrix and thus takes twice as long?